# Expected value of maximum of a constant and an absolute value of a standard normal

Tags: probability

If $X$ follow  standard normal distribution, what is   $E(\max(a,\left|X\right|)$, assuming $a>0$?

Since $\max(a,\left|X\right|)=\frac{1}{2}(a+\left|X\right|+\left|a-\left|X\right|\right|)$, taking the expectation from both sides shows us that calculating $E(\max(a,\left|X\right|))$ might be  replaced   by calculating $E(\left|a-\left|X\right|\right|)$ following the fact that $\left|X\right|$  has  half-normal distribution and the value of  $E\left|X\right|$   is known.

$E\max(a,\left|X\right|)=\int \max(a,\left|x\right|) f(x)dx=
\int_{\left|x\right|<a} af(x)dx+\int_{\left|x\right|>a} \left|x\right|f(x)dx=
a(2P(X<a)-1)+\int_{x>a} xf(x)dx-\int_{x<-a} xf(x)dx=2aP(X<a)-a+2\int_{a}^{\infty} xf(x)dx=2aP(X<a)-a+\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}a^2).$

Is this answer correct?

There is also a relevant post here [enter link description here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787314/expected-value-of-max-minx-c-f-when-x-is-a-gaussian-random-variable-and-c?rq=1)

Comment: I don't like the move, when you think that $\int_{0}^{a} x f(x)dx = P(0<X<a)$

Comment: I also don't like that you are writing $X$ under the integral, because $X$ actually a random value.

Comment: @ Eugene Sirkiza, I corrected,  how does it seem  now?

Comment: How can you explain my first comment?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, note please that we always write $Eg(X)=\int g(x)f_X(x)dx$

Comment: $P(0 < X < a) = \int_{0}^{a} f(x)dx$. I'm trying to explain that there is no $x$ under integral.

Comment: Now, it seems correct to me

Comment: Do not cross-post. Now answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/415819/expected-value-of-maximum-of-a-constant-and-an-absolute-value-of-a-standard-norm.